# Cannot open source file error but "go to definition" works

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have a file that starts with the following contents:

```
#pragma once
#include <winsock2.h>
#include "pluginterfaces/vst/ivstevents.h"
```

I am getting this error on the third line:

> Cannot open source file "pluginterfaces/vst/ivstevents.h" C/C++(1696)

However, when I right click on the file name and click "go to definition" the file ivstevents.h is found correctly and opens. The folder pluginterfaces is a direct child of the workspace folder, and I have the following in my c_cpp_properties.json:

```
"includePath": [
"${workspaceFolder}/**"
],
```

**How do I get rid of this error and enable intellisense to find the file correctly?**

Things I've tried so far:

- I have tried resetting the intellisense cache to no avail.
- If I specify the full relative path from my source file to the included file (#include "../../../pluginterfaces/vst/ivstevents.h") then intellisense finds it, but I should not have to do this if my include path is set correctly (nor is it feasible to do this change for every file in my project, because I am using a large library with many many include files).

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: OK: VSCode can find the header ... but your compiler can't.  Q: What C/C++ compiler have you integrated into VSCode?  Q: Have you configured a "-I" include command line parameter for the compiler anywhere in your C/C++ project?  EXAMPLE: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.2/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options

Comment: @paulsm4 you don't integrate a C++ compiler in VSC, VSC is an editor that can type commands in a terminal

Comment: @rioV8: you're correct,  VSCode is primarily an *editor*, not a compiler.  Hence the need to use it in conjunction with external tools: such as a GCC compiler.  Which is what I meant by "integration".  The OP needs to be aware of this.  He also needs to configure his project with the correct equivalent of the `-I` option ("header file include path" option) for his particular compiler/build tool.

Comment: The project does build fine, it's just the editor that's telling me this error. I'm using cmake to compile the project. I have the cmake and cmake tools extensions installed, and I have cmake configured to use Visual Studio Build Tools 2022 release compiler (this is on a windows machine). Thanks for help!

Comment: Sorry my hard drive failed and after reinstalling VS Code on a new one I'm unable to reproduce this error. Thanks to all who responded!

Answer (score 0):

[`${workspaceFolder}` will search through all subdirectories while `${workspaceFolder}/*` will not.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference#_browse-properties)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following:

```json
"browse": {
    "path": [
        "${workspaceFolder}"
    ]
},
```

I also suggest adding `"limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true`

so that your json looks something like:

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "browse": {
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "path": [
                    "${workspaceFolder}"
                ]
            },
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-msvc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

See [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/faq-cpp#_what-is-the-difference-between-includepath-and-browsepath) for more information.